# how to integrate gizmos widgets in wxformbuilder

Tags: wxpython, wxformbuilder

I am planning to use wxformbuilder to design application user interface. It's great tool and I like wxPython.

But i don't see gizmos widgets anywhere on the UI. I am particularly interested in gizmos.TreeListCtrl widget which supports tree with multi column entries.

Anybody has tried intergrating gizmos widget with wxformbuilder? is it possible even?

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is what i did, i added regular wxTreeCtrl from wxFB, then in the property pane under subclass, changed name to TreeListCtrl and header to wx.gizmos.

Additional settings (like adding multiple columns and all) needs to be done manually in the derived frame class in **init**
Event handlers can be added through wxFB and work correctly.